# Disable font smoothing in window 10 using registry and without restart / logout of computer

Tags: windows-10, powershell

Detail Information -

1) Press Window Key + R

2) Type regedit

3) Navigate to below path 
       Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop

4) Double click FontSmoothing name on right window panel and set the Value data to 0

5) restart the computer (or) log out and login

Result - Works Fine

Requirement - I dont want to restart / sign out from the computer to see the changes

Answer (score 0):

To set the registry variable, you can run the following:

```
Set-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop" -Name FontSmoothing -Value 0
```

read more about using the registry with powershell [here](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/09/11/how-to-get-edit-create-and-delete-registry-keys-with-powershell/)

To reload *most* of windows' display features, restart explorer.exe:

```
Stop-Process -ProcessName explorer
```

If restarting explorer does not apply this change, you'll need to research the process or service using that value and restart it instead.

Comment: Thank you and will try and post the result here